# Does thermodynamics only deal with homogenous systems?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, pressure, temperature, ergodicity

In thermodynamics, quantities like pressure, temperature and entropy are associated with overall states of a macroscopic system. In that case, we do not talk about "the quantity $Q$ at the point $p$ of the system" thinking of it as a continuum, for instance, we rather say "the quantity $Q$ of the system" as if it were the same for all of it.

In that sense, does thermodynamics only deal with homogenous systems? That is, do we always suppose that pressure, temperature and all those quantities are the same on the entire system under study? If so, what is the need and motivation for this?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any source that would claim you need homogeneity to do thermodynamics. Textbooks might usually assume systems have a single constant pressure and temperature because it's easier, but it's not a requirement.

Intensive variables can be functions of position. Any discussion of the buoyant force needs position-dependent pressure. Any discussion of the heat equation needs position-dependent temperature, etc.

You can't find the entropy at a certain point, but that's just because it's extensive; you need to find the entropy of the entire system. It's the same as how you can't find the energy at a certain point, or the mass at a certain point. What you can do is find densities of these things. Mass density, energy density, specific entropy, etc. You can then integrate these densities over the entire system to find the mass, energy, and entropy.

Comment: Problems with position dependent thermodynamic variables of the kind that you are describing are NOT part of thermodynamics. Indeed, without ad-hoc assumptions thermodynamics has nothing to say about them, at all. Buoyancy is not a thermodynamics, but a fluid mechanics problem. One can find engineering textbooks which do not make a clear distinction of where thermodynamics ends and where linearized-non-equilibrium thermodynamics models begin. This makes some students believe that these models have the same physical meaning as thermodynamics proper, but that's not the case.

Comment: Would you like to give reasons to support your assertions?

Comment: @CuriousOne, gradient of pressure does not necessarily mean the situation is non-equilibrium. As long as the state of the fluid in gravitational field changes quasi-statically and is close to thermodynamic equilibrium, thermodynamics (1.+2.law) is applicable. See for example Landau & Lifshitz, first chapters of Fluid mechanics.

Comment: See particularly the sections 3,4 of the first chapter.

Comment: @CuriousOne, the buoyant force correspond to the generalized force $Y$ but not the pressure $p$, thermodynamics (1st and 2nd law) is applicable, the generalized force $Y$ and the position variable $x$ that corresponded to IS a part of thermodynamics.

 $dU=TdS+Ydx-pdV+\sum\mu dN$

Comment: @JánLalinský: I didn't say that the situation in buoyancy is non-equilibrium but that it is part of mechanics and not part of thermodynamics. There is no temperature and no pressure dependence in a basic buoyancy setup. It is simply Newtonian forces acting on Newtonian masses.

Comment: @Freeman: I can analyze buoyancy without any regards to T, dV, dN and the chemical potential. You have basically constructed a physical Rube-Goldberg machine that pretends that buoyancy is a thermodynamic phenomenon, when, in reality, it is not. That's bad physics motivated by bad thinking.

Comment: @CuriousOne, if we want to find out what is the pressure variation of fluid in equilibrium in gravitational field, we will need to apply ideas of both mechanics and thermodynamics. It is not thermodynamics of heat engines but still it deals with temperature, pressure and energy. The same principles work here, only they need to be applied locally.

Comment: @JánLalinský: If no temperature and no heat is involved in buoyancy, which of the laws of thermodynamics are you using for your calculations? Zero defines an order relation for temperature - it's not needed. One defines the equivalence of heat and energy - it's not needed. Two expresses that heat can only flow from hot to cold - it's not needed. Three allows us to define an absolute temperature scale and it regulates that there can be no perpetual motion from thermodynamics - it's not needed.

Comment: @CuriousOne, I am not talking about buouyancy, but about calculating pressure distribution in a static fluid. Please check out the 3rd section of *Fluid mechanics* or try to calculate it yourself for general fluid. You will find Gibbs energy or the equation of state of the fluid plays role.

Comment: @JánLalinský: The net force on the volume elements in a liquid in gravity is called buoyancy, just the same as the net for on any other body in the liquid, and it does not require any theory of heat (aka thermodynamics). Sorry... you seem to have a very hard time admitting that you are wrong. I will leave it at that, because any further "discussion" seems pointless until you man up to none of the laws of thermodynamics being involved in this simple phenomenon.

Comment: @CuriousOne - I stand with Ján Lalinský here. Take thermodynamics away from fluid mechanics and you have next to nothing. Thermodynamics is an integral part of fluid dynamics.

Comment: @DavidHammen: When I was in school they taught fluid dynamics in one course and temperature and heat were not mentioned once. And in the class on thermodynamics we didn't talk once about linearized non-equilibrium thermodynamics. It was in the class on plasma physics where the two came together with electromagnetism... of course, the theory book which I used to learn plasma physics from warned explicitly not to take linearized transport equations too seriously, since they were nothing but ad-hoc models that didn't even agree with microscopic derivations of these processes.

Comment: @CuriousOne, I believe that you “can analyze buoyancy without any regards to T, dV, dN and the chemical potential”, but it only means that you fixed $T, V, N$, buoyant and other generalized force are the studying objects if the potential energies to be considered as the parts of the internal energy $U$. Thermodynamics includes mechanics process.

Comment: @Freeman: That's what fluid mechanics does: it neglects thermodynamic effects. Do you see temperature anywhere in the Navier-Stokes equation? On the other hand, where does the momentum of a flowing volume element show up in thermodynamics? There are combinations of both, but they need to use additional ad-hoc assumptions, which in engineering models usually take the form of linear transport assumptions. Those, however, are not fundamental physics, but merely models that work in relatively narrow areas of engineering applications.

Answer (score 2):

**Thermodynamics does deal with inhomogeneities and non-equilibrium conditions...**

...but indeed it requires some "*macroscopic* smearing" of quantities. Problems like diffusion of particles, or heat are dealt with and very well explained by thermodynamics, specifically with Maxwell's Thermodynamic Potentials formalism. But the thing is, the thermodynamic variables of a system are defined over *macroscopic* portions of it, because **Thermodynamics is a *macroscopic* theory**. Variables like density, or chemical concentration are averages over certain *macroscopic* volume; and temperature has no meaning without equilibrium! (although it is used other fields of physics where analogies allow for convenient modified definitions)

I have emphasized *macroscopic* because I wanted to specify that it need not be a ~$10^{23}$ components system. A macroscopic system or portion of the system can be that whose size is large enough that the mean value Energy or Mass or any extensive variable (additive variable) has small enough fluctuations.

**Summarizing: Thermodynamics deals with inhomogeneities and explains the evolution of a system towards equilibrium, but as long as these inhomogeneities are of *macroscopic* order.**

Answer (score 1):

> Thermodynamics only deals with homogenous systems? That is, we suppose always that pressure, temperature and all those quantities are the same on the entire system under study?

Of course not. Thermodynamics would be a rather useless field of study if it only addressed homogeneous systems. That thermodynamics does far more than that is what makes it instead so incredibly useful.

Even at the most basic level, all but the zeroth law of thermodynamics addresses systems that are not homogeneous. The first law addresses heat flow, the second heat engines. How can you have heat flow or a heat engine if everything is of the same composition and is at the same pressure, temperature, and density?

Intrinsic variables such as pressure, temperature, and density are intrinsically local. Even extrinsic variables such as volume, mass, entropy, and energy can be made local either by looking at their thermodynamic conjugate or by looking at a ration of two extrinsic variables. It's only in elementary treatments that students are taught to look at a system as having one pressure, one temperature, one density, throughout some volume. This is done is because introductory level students don't yet have the mathematical prowess to understand a more thorough description.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the system down into smaller subsystems.  If we have a room with an inlet of air at one corner and an outlet at the opposite corner, we can make a grid of cells of whatever spacing we want.  We can then assume the pressure and temperature are uniform within the cell and compute the flows between the cells.  This is what the weather people do.  The grid spacing is limited by our calculation power.

Answer (score 0):

This topic makes some sense, “Thermodynamics quantities like pressure, temperature and entropy are associated with overall states of a macroscopic system” or associated with overall states of a local, this is a fact.
In the equation
\begin{align}dU=TdS-pdV+Ydx+\sum_j\mu_jdN_j\end{align}
$T, S, p, V $ “are associated with overall states of a macroscopic system” or a local, $Y, x, \mu_j, N_j$ can be, but not a requirement. So thermodynamics now is a “Grey box theory”. In some new theoretical models[1], the Intensive variables $T, p$ can be instead, by the distribution of the extensive variables associated with them. For example, consider an idea gas or photon gas, using $q$ denotes the energy of thermal motion within the system, name as the internal heat energy, then we have
\begin{align}dU=dq.\end{align}
The entropy of the system
\begin{align}dS=\frac{dU}{T}+\frac{pdV}{T}=\frac{dq}{T}+\frac{pdV}{T}.\end{align}
For an idea gas, $T=q/iNk$ and $pV=NkT$, such that
\begin{align}dS=\frac{iNk}{q}dq+\frac{Nk}{V}dV.\end{align}
For a photon gas, $q=3pV$ and $T=q/3NR_{p}$, where $R_{\{p\}}$=$[\zeta (4)/\zeta (3)]k$, $\zeta (3)$ and $\zeta (4)$ are the Riemann zeta functions.
Such that, we get
\begin{align}dS=\frac{3NR_{\{p\}}}{q}dq+\frac{NR_{\{p\}}}{V}dV.\end{align}
It implies, for an idea gas or photon gas
\begin{align}dS=\frac{iNR_{\{k\}}}{q}dq+\frac{NR_{\{k\}}}{V}dV. \end{align}
Where $i$ is number of the degrees of freedom of the particles, and $R_{\{k\}}$ denotes the system constant, for an idea gas $R_{\{k\}}$=$k$, and for a photon gas $R_{\{k\}}$=$R_{\{p\}}$.
All of the variables in the equation are extensive variables, and an inference for the first term can be made to dynamics
\begin{align}
\frac{iNR_{\{k\}}}{q}dq\rightarrow R_{\{k\}}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\sum_{s=1}^s d\ln\epsilon_{j\{s\}}.\end{align}
Where $\epsilon_{j}$ is the kinetic energy of the particle $j$, and $s$ is the degrees of freedom of the particles.
So, thermodynamic quantities are associated with overall states of a macroscopic system, but this “associated with”  is not a requirement.

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4284v5

Answer (score 0):

As thermodynamic deals with macroscopic properties like temperature , preesure, which doesn't change with time  for system in equillibrium state  it only occur if system is homogeneous  b'coz heterogeneous system can't have constant P ,T

Answer (score 0):

**TL; DR: the probability density is *homogeneously* spread over all the states with the same energy**

**Thermodynamics vs. Statistical physics**
Let me first point out that *thermodynamics* and *statistical physics* are not the same thing: these are two descriptions of the same phenomena, one of which is phenomenological (thermodynamics) and the other is microscopic (statistical physics).

**Non-equilibrium thermodynamics**
Further, the question seems to refer to *equilibrium thermodynamics/statistical-physics*. Both of these have extensions (in fact multiple extensions) for treating non-equilibrium (and thus non-homogeneous) systems.

**So, homogeneous or not?**

> In that sense, does thermodynamics only deal with homogenous systems?

Directly extending phenomenological thermodynamic description to inhomogeneous systems might be hard. From the point of view of statistical physics, we do make homogeneity assumption, but somewhat indirect: we assume that all the phase space configurations with the same energy (and same value of some other parameters) are equally probable, and that system will visit all of them, so that we can replace the time averaging by ensemble averaging. Tu put it into more "homogeneity" language: we do assume that
**the probability density is homogeneously spread over all the states with the same energy**. This is known as *microcanonical ensemble*, and serves to build canonical and grand canonical cases.

**Homogenuity of quantities**

> That is, do we always suppose that pressure, temperature and all those quantities are the same on the entire system under study?

Pressure and temperature are *intrinsic* variables that characterize the system as a whole. As such, they say nothing about whetehr the system is homogeneous or not. What make them seem like specific to homogeneous system is the interpretation of these quantities as in terms of ideal gas, where pressure comes from the molecules colliding against the container walls, while the temperature is the average kinetic energy of these molecules. These quantities (and many other, such as, e.g., magnetic moment) can be however defined in very general thermodynamic ways, without resorting to their microscopic interpretation (note how thermodynamics here is more convenient than statistical physics):

- *Temperature* as the derivative of the internal energy in respect to entropy $$T=\left(\frac{\partial U }{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}\text{ or } \frac{1}{T}=\left(\frac{\partial S }{\partial U}\right)_{V,N}$$
- *Pressure* as the derivative of the internal energy in respect to volume
  $$P=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_{S,N}$$

*Remark:* equating these with the mechanistic notions of pressure and temperature as defined for the ideal gas may sometimes be tricky however - see, e.g., [Significance of Stokes hypothesis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/689573/247642).